# How to set a back ground image to the div tag in angular 5 after obtaining the image from a server side resource method?

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi Currently I am having a angular 5 GUI and a spring boot application. I am having an angular component for displaying an image . However the image is not getting displayed.

avatar.component.html

```
<div class="avatar-circle" [style.background-image]="avatarBgImageStyle" [ngClass]="avatarClasses">
  <fa-icon *ngIf="!user?.avatar" icon="user"></fa-icon>
</div>
<div class="labels" *ngIf="user && (showFullName || showAccount || showAuthority)">
  <div *ngIf="showFullName" class="full-name">{{ fullName }}</div>
  <div *ngIf="showAccount && user.account" class="secondary-text">{{ user.account.name }}</div>
  <div *ngIf="showAuthority && user.authorities && user.authorities.length" class="secondary-text">{{ 'USER_ROLES.' + authority | translate }}</div>
</div>
```

avatar.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

import { User } from '../../models';
import { getUserFullName } from '../../utils';
import { FilesService } from '../../services';

@Component({
  selector: 'pc-avatar',
  templateUrl: './avatar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./avatar.component.scss']
})
export class AvatarComponent {
  @Input() user: User;
  @Input() showFullName = false;
  @Input() showAccount = false;
  @Input() showAuthority = false;
  @Input() bgColor = 'secondary';
  @Input() textColor = 'brand-secondary';

  @HostBinding('class')
  @Input()
  size: 'md' | 'lg' | 'xl' = 'md';

  get fullName() {
    return getUserFullName(this.user);
  }

  get authority() {
    return this.user.authorities[0];
  }

  get avatarBgImageStyle(): string {
    if (!this.user || !this.user.avatar) {
      return 'none';
    }

    const url = this.filesService.getFileUrl(this.user.avatar);
    return `url(${url})`;
  }

  get avatarClasses(): string[] {
    return [`bg-${this.bgColor}`, `text-${this.textColor}`];
  }

  constructor(private filesService: FilesService) {}
}
```

in the avatar.component.html you can see i am setting [style.background-image]="avatarBgImageStyle" it calls the method avatarBgImageStyle() in the avatar.component.ts and returns a string ( for example http://localhost:8080/api/files/file-id . my spring boot application has a resource method that can serve the file request. this resource is secured.

```
/**
 * REST controller for managing File.
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class FileResource {
 @GetMapping("/files/{id}")
    @Timed
    @Secured({AuthoritiesConstants.GLOBAL_ADMIN, AuthoritiesConstants.ACCOUNT_ADMIN, AuthoritiesConstants.CAMPAIGN_MANAGER, AuthoritiesConstants.TEAM_MEMBER})
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> getFile(@PathVariable UUID id) {
        log.debug("REST request to get File : {}", id);

        File file = fileService.findOne(id)
            .orElseThrow(FileNotFoundException::new);

        byte[] bytes = Bytes.getArray(file.getContent());

        ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(bytes);

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .contentLength(bytes.length)
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(file.getType()))
            .body(resource);
    }
}
```

when i check the developer tools i can see that the UI is issuing requests to server for image files , however the get requests are missing the Authorisation header. I am already having http interceptors in place to add authentication headers. however since the background image url is set to the div tag it dont call the http interceptor to attach authentication token and in the developer tool i can see 403 forbidden errors.

any idea what would be my code looks like if i want to access a file from the server as bytes and setting it as background image to the div tag.

I am having a FilesService class .

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { FileResponse, AppConfig } from '../models';
import { ConfigService } from './config.service';

@Injectable()
export class FilesService {
  config: AppConfig = this.configService.config;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private configService: ConfigService) {}

  get(id: string) {
    return this.http.get<FileResponse>(`${this.config.api}/files/${id}`);
  }

  upload(formData: FormData) {
    return this.http.post<FileResponse>(`${this.config.api}/files`, formData);
  }

  getFileUrl(id: string) {
    return `${this.config.api}/files/${id}`;
  }
}
```

this is my interceptor that add json web tokens

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (
      request.url.startsWith('/assets') ||
      request.url.startsWith('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap')
    ) {
      return next.handle(request);
    }

    const authenticationService = this.injector.get(AuthenticationService);
    const notificationService = this.injector.get(NotificationsService);
    const router = this.injector.get(Router);

    if (!!authenticationService.token) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${authenticationService.token}`
        }
      });
    }

    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError(err => {
        if (
          request.url !== authenticationService.loginUrl &&
          err instanceof HttpErrorResponse &&
          err.status === 401
        ) {
          authenticationService.logout();
          notificationService.stopInterval();
          router.navigate(['/login'], {
            queryParams: {
              returnUrl: router.url
            }
          });
        }

        return _throw(err);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

appreciate any help 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="avatar-circle" [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': avatarBgImageStyle !== 'none' ? avatarBgImageStyle : ''" [ngClass]="avatarClasses">
  <fa-icon *ngIf="!user?.avatar" icon="user"></fa-icon>
</div>
```

Did you try this approach? I'm not entirely sure how that works with async obtained values, if that'll update once the variable is set, but I would suggest that you give it a try like this (sadly not able to try that at the moment myself).

Comment: i doubt it will work because avatarBgImageStyle() method returns a string like this url('http://localhost:8080/api/files/23905bd4-730e-11e9-a923-1681be663d3e') however after i securing my resource method with     @Secured({AuthoritiesConstants.GLOBAL_ADMIN,AuthoritiesConstants.ACCOUNT_ADMIN,AuthoritiesConstants.CAMPAIGN_MANAGER,AuthoritiesConstants.TEAM_MEMBER})  it  expects a json web token .  the real issue i can identify is we are not sending the json webtokens .

Comment: For JSON WebToken you should implement a `HttpInterceptor` that will append the token to each and every request that is sent.

Comment: yes i am aware of that .just now posted my interceptor.  i think the interceptor wornt be triggered when you set a url to the backgroung-image in a div tag. probably need to issue an http request to my file resouce and get it as an byte[] and have to do it believe . but no idea how the code looks like . thank you

Answer (score 0):

use this format in your div:

```
[style.background-image]=" 'url(' +avatarBgImageStyle + ')'"
```

Comment: this will potentially resolve to url(url(23905bd4-730e-11e9-a923-1681be663d3e)) so doubt it might work

Comment: thank you . you can see that function in the file avatar.component.ts. get avatarBgImageStyle(): string {
    if (!this.user || !this.user.avatar) {
      return 'none';
    }

    const url = this.filesService.getFileUrl(this.user.avatar);
    return `url(${url})`;
  } .

Comment: "avatarBgImageStyle" this shuold be image url then my code will works.